# How do I extract and concatenate values from a list of dictionaries using Jinja?

Tags: sql, jinja2, amazon-redshift, dbt

I am currently using Redshift and I have a `super` data type column that contains an array of varying length (i.e.; containing 0-N number of elements) whose elements are dictionaries (JSONs). For example

```json
[{"id":1234},{"id":5678},{"id":90}]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select
    id,
    split_to_array(
        json_extract_path_text(
            json_extract_path_text(tests, 'tests', true), 'ids', true), ',') as ids_array,
    {% set temp_list = [] %}
    {% set itr = ids_array %}
    {% for i in itr %}
        {{ temp_list.append(i.value) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ temp_list|join(',') }} as ids
from schema_name.table_name
```

Basically, I just want to create a *new derived column* whose values are just a  comma separated string like:

```
1234,5678,90
```

I know how to use the python `join` function to concat a simple list of strings but I do not know how to do it for a list of dicts.
My `temp_list` is returning an empty string and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a single attribute of a list of dictionaries with the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map), then, indeed, use a [`join` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) to create the comma separated string from the resulting list.

So the code:

```
{{ [{"id":1234},{"id":5678},{"id":90}] | map(attribute='id') | join(',') }}
```

Will give you your expected string:

```
1234,5678,90
```